# How to change "?" symbol in URL by .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

May be its a simple question, but I can`t resolv it ;(

I have URL:

```
http://example.net/index.php/topic?122.0.html
```

And I need just to change "?" symbol to ",". Like this:

```
http://example.net/index.php/topic,122.0.html
```

This rule dont works:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?(.*)$ /$1,$2
```

Im tried also with \%3F and no result.
Im testing it on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match query string using `RewriteRule`. Use this rule instead in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php/.*)$ /$1,%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,NE,NC,R=302]
```